# Deductive Multiple Checkbox Selection Product Filter

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql

What I'm trying to do is to make a filter for products, I'm retrieving products from the database through  datatable, and I want my filter to hide other option if they don't match. For example: I have BRAND AND MODEL. if I select Acer brand. the datatable will display all acer products but I also want the contents of model filter to update based on the acer brand. so I will only see acer model only

Here's for the front end

```
                        <!-- FILTER FOR BRAND -->
                    <?php      

                $query = "SELECT * FROM category where name='$namesss' and filter1='on'";
                $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
                $statement->execute();
                $result = $statement->fetchAll();
                foreach($result as $row)
                {
                    ?>

                    <div class="list-group">
                        <h3>BRAND</h3>
                        <div style="height: 180px; overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden;">
                            <?php

                $query = "SELECT DISTINCT(BRAND) FROM prod WHERE DCS='$namesss' ORDER BY BRAND ASC";
                $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
                $statement->execute();
                $result = $statement->fetchAll();
                foreach($result as $row)
                {
                ?>
                            <div class="list-group-item checkbox">
                                <label><input type="checkbox" class="common_selector BRAND" value="<?php echo $row['BRAND']; ?>">
                                    <?php echo $row['BRAND']; ?></label>




                            </div>
                            <?php
                }

                ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php 
                }
                    ?> 




                    <!-- FILTER FOR MODEL -->
                    <?php      

                $query = "SELECT * FROM category where name='$namesss' and filter3='on'";
                $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
                $statement->execute();
                $result = $statement->fetchAll();
                foreach($result as $row)
                {
                    ?>
                    <div class="list-group">
                        <h3>MODEL</h3>
                        <div style="height: 250px; overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden;">
                            <?php
                $query = "
                SELECT DISTINCT(Model) FROM prod WHERE DCS='$namesss'  ORDER BY Model ASC
                ";
                $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
                $statement->execute();
                $result = $statement->fetchAll();
                foreach($result as $row)
                {
                ?>
                            <div class="list-group-item checkbox">
                                <label><input type="checkbox" class="common_selector Model" value="<?php echo $row['Model']; ?>">
                                    <?php echo $row['Model']; ?> </label>
                            </div>
                            <?php
                }
                ?>
```

here's for the fetch data

```
                <?php  

            //fetch_data.php

            include('database_connection.php');

            if(isset($_POST["action"]))
            { 
                $query = "
                    SELECT * FROM prod where product_status ='0' 
                ";
                if(isset($_POST["minimum_price"], $_POST["maximum_price"]) && !empty($_POST["minimum_price"]) && !empty($_POST["maximum_price"]))
                {
                    $query .= "
                     AND SRP BETWEEN '".$_POST["minimum_price"]."' AND '".$_POST["maximum_price"]."'
                    ";
                }
                if(isset($_POST["BRAND"]))
                {
                    $brand_filter = implode("','", $_POST["BRAND"]);
                    $query .= "
                     AND BRAND IN('".$brand_filter."')
                    ";
                }
                if(isset($_POST["DCS"]))
                {
                    $DCS_filter = implode("','", $_POST["DCS"]);
                    $query .= "
                     AND DCS IN('".$DCS_filter."')
                    ";
                }
                if(isset($_POST["Str"]))
                {
                    $Str_filter = implode("','", $_POST["Str"]);
                    $query .= "
                     AND Str IN('".$Str_filter."')
                    ";
                }
                if(isset($_POST["Model"]))
                {
                    $Model_filter = implode("','", $_POST["Model"]);
                    $query .= "
                     AND Model IN('".$Model_filter."')
                    ";
                }
```

Comment: Your checkboxes don't have names. Use array names (having brackets) `<input name="BRAND[]" value="..."`

Comment: already tried but it doesn't work. i want to replicate the product filter on this website https://www.abenson.com/computers-gadget/notebook.html

Comment: It does work for more than 20 years. "doesn't work" is no description of an issue.

Comment: so you want to display model based on selected brand, have you tried anything.